Issus with permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android
I'm ussing react-native-ble-manager, when BleManager.scan() function is called, i get "Need abdroid.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.connect,.AttributionSource@bb97c7c7:GattService registerScanner".
I was looking for an answer to fix this here, but anything worked.
this is my AndroidManifest.xml
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.anonymous.ecgapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

and I was following a tutorial for reference:
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-native-ble-manager-mobile-app/
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import {
    Text,
    Alert,
    View,
    FlatList,
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    SafeAreaView,
    NativeModules,
    useColorScheme,
    TouchableOpacity,
    NativeEventEmitter,
    PermissionsAndroid
    } from 'react-native';
    import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';

    const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
    const BleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule);

    const Example = () => {
        const [isScanning, setIsScanning] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
            BleManager.start({showAlert: false}).then(() => {
              console.log('BleManager initialized');
              handleGetConnectedDevices();
            });
    
            BleManager.enableBluetooth().then(() => {
              console.log('Bluetooth is turned on!');
            });
    
            let stopDiscoverListener = BleManagerEmitter.addListener(
              'BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral',
              peripheral => {
                peripherals.set(peripheral.id, peripheral);
                setDiscoveredDevices(Array.from(peripherals.values()));
              },
            );
            let stopConnectListener = BleManagerEmitter.addListener(
              'BleManagerConnectPeripheral',
              peripheral => {
                console.log('BleManagerConnectPeripheral:', peripheral);
              },
            );
            let stopScanListener = BleManagerEmitter.addListener(
              'BleManagerStopScan',
              () => {
                setIsScanning(false);
                console.log('scan stopped');
              },
            );
    

            if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
              PermissionsAndroid.check(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
              ).then(result => {
                if (result) {
                  console.log('Permission location is OK');
                } else {
                  PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                  ).then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                      console.log('User accepted location');
                    } else {
                      console.log('User refused location');
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            }else{
              console.log("version is: ",Platform.Version);
            }

            return () => {
              stopDiscoverListener.remove();
              stopConnectListener.remove();
              stopScanListener.remove();
            };
        }, []);

    const startScan = () => {
      if (!isScanning) {
        BleManager.scan([], 5, true)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Scanning...');
            setIsScanning(true);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
    };
    const scanPermission = () =>{
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
        PermissionsAndroid.check(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        ).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            console.log('Permission is OK');
            startScan();
          } else {
            PermissionsAndroid.request(
              PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            ).then(res => {
              if (res == true) {
                console.log('User accepted scan',res);
                startScan();
              } else if(!res) {
                console.log('User refused scan',res);
              }
              else {
                console.log('Response Request was',res);
              }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('[Request error]',err);
            });
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('[Permision Scan error]',err)
        });
      }
    }
    ....

what i do is call to scanPermission() and if it is granted then call to startScan()
this is my app.json
{
    "expo": {
      "name": "ecg-app",
      "slug": "ecg-app",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "orientation": "portrait",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
      "plugins": [
        [
          "expo-build-properties",
          {
            "android": {
              "compileSdkVersion": 34,
              "targetSdkVersion": 34,
              "buildToolsVersion": "34.0.0"
            },
            "ios": {
              "deploymentTarget": "13.4"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "assetBundlePatterns": [
        "**/*"
      ],
      "ios": {
        "supportsTablet": true
      },
      "android": {
        "adaptiveIcon": {
          "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
          "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "package": "com.anonymous.ecgapp",
        "Permissions":[
          "ACCES_FINE_LOCATION",
          "BLUETOOTH",
          "BLUETOORH_ADMIN",
          "BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
          ]
        },
      }
    }

this is what i have on my code, i'm ussing de runtime Permission as required
try with the location permission runtime, whitout it because they say it is no required on android 13 that is  the version what my device use.
when the permission runtime require for BLUETOOTH_SCAN is called, i verified the response is never_ask_again, but when i verified the permission setting on my device it is granted for my app
i'm ussing expo app, but, on developmen build mode using eas build for android ussing: "eas build --profile development --platform android"
